# Enable edit only for the selected row in the table

Tags: java, javafx

I am fairly new in JavaFX. I have a table with multiple columns and an Edit `button` in each row. Whenever I click on the `Edit` 1st cell is selected for edit of that row. Everything goes fine but the problem is whenever I select a row and click on a cell of it also gets in edit mode though I have not clicked `Edit`. I think it's because I have made `tableView.setEditable(true)` but I want to enable edit only when I click Edit button and only for that row, not others when I double click/ single click. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884190/row-edit-in-tableview) but they have solved it by a pop-up. I don't want that.
In the `initialize()` method I tried this way but it's not working exactly. Can anyone show me the correct way to do this, please?

```
tableBuilding.setRowFactory(tv -> {
                TableRow<ModelBrBuilding> row = new TableRow<>();
                row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                        e.consume();
                    }
                });

               row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,event -> {
                if ( event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY   && event.getClickCount() == 2  ) {
                    event.consume();
                }
                });
                return row ;
            });
```

and my button action looks like

```
 EditButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{                  
                    TableRow row = cell.getTableRow();
                    tableBuilding.requestFocus();
                    tableBuilding.getSelectionModel().select(row.getIndex());            
                        int i=tableBuilding.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                        tableBuilding.edit(i,colName);                                                          
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant solution to this, but you could simply set the `TableView` editable right before you call `tableView.edit(int, TableColumn)` and then set it back to not being editable when the edit is either committed or cancelled. Or you can do this set\unset editable thing on each specific `TableColumn`.

For instance, in your `Button`'s action handler:

```
button.setOnAction(evt -> {
    evt.consume();
    tableView.requestFocus();
    tableView.edit(-1, null); // cancel any current edit if there is one
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(tableCell.getIndex());
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    tableView.edit(tableCell.getIndex(), tableColumn);
});
```

And then for the `TableColumn`:

```
EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<S, T>> handler = evt -> tableView.setEditable(false);
tableColumn.setOnEditCancel(handler);
tableColumn.setOnEditCommit(handler);
// or you can use the addEventHandler(EventType, EventHandler) method
```